# rails carrierwave gem error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I have succsfuly set up an image upload with the `carrierwave` gem.

but when I try to add an optional online url like so:

```
 <%= form_for @rating, :html => {:multipart=>true} do |f| %>

    <div class="field">
       <%= f.file_field :pic_url %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :remote_pic_url_url, 'or image url' %>
      <br/>
      <%= f.text_field :remote_pic_url_url %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit 'Upload Picture', :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

then I get this error:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes:
```

my model is

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :pic_url, :rating

  mount_uploader :pic_url , ImageUploader
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be able to mass-assign the `remote_pic_url_url` attribute:

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :pic_url, :remote_pic_url_url, :rating

  mount_uploader :pic_url , ImageUploader
end
```

Comment: ??, I'm new to rails, what does that mean? I was under the impression that remote_{columnName}_url is the convention for adding additional url field in `carrierwave`

Comment: When you use a form to create (or update) a model object, Rails will not permit you to set anything not specified in the `attr_accessible` white-list (unless you use a black-list method like `attr_protected`).  This is to prevent unauthorized access to attributes not intended for modification via UI.  So any field in the form for your model, needs to have a corresponding entry in the `attr_accessible` list.  See [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html) for more info on this.